# Kibana Visualizations with JSON Codec

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I set up a server with ELK stack and started feeding logs into it.
The logs are in JSON format, so I edited the LogStash conf file to use the JSON Codec.

When I enter the Kibana Discover page I see that the JSON is indeed decoded - it's no longer just a long string, every field is separated as it should be.

But now I want to create visualizations based on these fields, for example: There is a field named "service" which names the service which created the log record. I would like to create a vertical bar visualization using the "service" field for the X-axis.

How do I do such a thing?

Comment: Can you share your Logstash config? You probably need to convert a few fields.

Comment: When you go to Visualize and select 'Vertical bar chart', look under "Buckets" for "X-Axis", select "Terms" and then your "service" field.

Comment: @AlainCollins Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create visualizations easily by following below mentioned steps:-

1. Click on Visualize Tab
2. Select Visualization type as **"Vertical Bar Chart"**
3. Select search from data source
4. Select count in Y-Axis
5. Select Terms in X-Axis & select your field named as **service**